# Как добавить текстовый блок на Circle в yandex maps?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

[image: подпись в нижней позиции окружности]

Возможно ли реализовать подпись (1км, 2км) внутри окружности как на скриншоте ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать кастомные метки со смещением от центра окружности, найденном методом [solveDirectProblem](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ICoordSystem-docpage/#method_detail__solveDirectProblem).

Для центра окружностей **coords** нужно определить смещение:

```
var startPoint = coords;
var azimuth = Math.PI;
var direction = [Math.cos(azimuth), Math.sin(azimuth)];
var coords1km = ymaps.coordSystem.geo.solveDirectProblem(startPoint, direction, 1000).endPoint;
var coords2km = ymaps.coordSystem.geo.solveDirectProblem(startPoint, direction, 2000).endPoint;
```

Создать шаблоны для кастомных CSS-меток:

```
var squareLayout1 = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="placemark_layout_container"><div class="square_layout">1км</div></div>');
```

...и оформить стиль:

```
.placemark_layout_container {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Квадратный макет метки */
.square_layout {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: -15px;
    color: black;
}
```

Ну и добавить метки в вычисленные координаты:

```
var squarePlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark(
    coords1km, {}, {iconLayout: squareLayout1});
var squarePlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark(
    coords2km, {}, {iconLayout: squareLayout2});
myMap.geoObjects.add(squarePlacemark1).add(squarePlacemark2);
```

Рабочий вариант на фиддле: https://jsfiddle.net/Coroner1st/d3rx5qo0/17/

Comment: Спасибо! жесть, но работает)) сам бы такое не придумал

Comment: Пожалуйста! За основу по меткам был использован пример яндекса https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape , который совмещён с solveDirectProblem из их же документации.

Comment: Тоже думал, меткой кастомной делать текст, но не знал каким образом я смогу вычислить координаты нижней части окружности